# Unable to connect to local Fedora Samba share. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: configuration, samba, fedora, network-attached-storage

New to networking. Created a samba share in Fedora Server. This samba share is supposed to connect to a raid0 pool (2x4TB WD Red) that I created. The mount point of the raid0 pool is `/raid0pool`.
The share file is set to be `/raid0pool/raid0share`

But, I am unable to connect from other local machines, including Windows 10 and Fedora Workstation. On windows 10 client I have tried entering connection addresses such as `\\192.168.5.207`, `\\192.168.5.207\raid0share\`, and `\\192.168.5.207\raid0pool\raid0share`. No luck at all. On Fedora workstation client I have entered in addresses such as `smb://192.168.5.207/raid0share` amd `smb://192.168.5.207/raid0pool/raid0share` with no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for any feedback.

EDIT edit smb.conf the samba share time to 'raid0share' as opposed to 'share' to reflect feedback. However, connection issue still persists

Included is the set of commands I used to set up samba, as well as my smb.conf file

```
[user@fedora-server /]$ sudo systemctl status smb
○ smb.service - Samba SMB Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/smb.service; disabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:smbd(8)
             man:samba(7)
             man:smb.conf(5)
[user@fedora-server /]$ ^C
[user@fedora-server /]$ sudo systemctl enable smb --now
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/smb.service → /usr/lib/systemd/system/smb.service.
[user@fedora-server /]$ sudo systemctl status smb
● smb.service - Samba SMB Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/smb.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-03-30 18:29:31 PDT; 1s ago
       Docs: man:smbd(8)
             man:samba(7)
             man:smb.conf(5)
   Main PID: 1517 (smbd)
     Status: "smbd: ready to serve connections..."
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 16590)
     Memory: 10.0M
        CPU: 41ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/smb.service
             ├─1517 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
             ├─1519 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
             └─1520 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group

Mar 30 18:29:31 fedora-server systemd[1]: Starting smb.service - Samba SMB Daemon...
Mar 30 18:29:31 fedora-server smbd[1517]: [2023/03/30 18:29:31.438343,  0] ../../source3/smbd/server.c:1741(main)
Mar 30 18:29:31 fedora-server smbd[1517]:   smbd version 4.17.6 started.
Mar 30 18:29:31 fedora-server smbd[1517]:   Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2022
Mar 30 18:29:31 fedora-server systemd[1]: Started smb.service - Samba SMB Daemon.
[user@fedora-server /]$ ^C
[user@fedora-server /]$ firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
FedoraServer
  interfaces: enp4s0
[user@fedora-server /]$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=FedoraServer --add-service=samba
success
[user@fedora-server /]$ sudo firewall-cmd --reload
success
[user@fedora-server /]$ sudo smbpasswd -a user
New SMB password:
Retype new SMB password:
Added user user.
[user@fedora-server /]$ cd/
bash: cd/: No such file or directory
[user@fedora-server /]$ cd /
[user@fedora-server /]$ ls
afs  bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  raid0pool  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
[user@fedora-server /]$ cd
[user@fedora-server ~]$ mkdir /raid0pool/raid0share
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/raid0pool/raid0share’: Permission denied
[user@fedora-server ~]$ sudo mkdir /raid0pool/raid0share
[user@fedora-server ~]$ cd /raid0pool
[user@fedora-server raid0pool]$ ls
lost+found  raid0share
[user@fedora-server raid0pool]$ cd
[user@fedora-server ~]$ sudo semanage fcontext --add --type "samba_share_t" "/raid0pool/raid0share(/.*)?"
[user@fedora-server ~]$ sudo restorecon -R ~/share
restorecon: lstat(/home/user/share) failed: No such file or directory
[user@fedora-server ~]$ sudo restorecon -R /raid0pool/raid0share
[user@fedora-server ~]$ sudo nano /etc/samba/smb/conf
[user@fedora-server ~]$ sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
[sudo] password for user: 
[user@fedora-server ~]$ 
[user@fedora-server ~]$ cd /
[user@fedora-server /]$ ls
afs  bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  raid0pool  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
[user@fedora-server /]$ cd /raid0pool
[user@fedora-server raid0pool]$ ls
lost+found  raid0share
[user@fedora-server raid0pool]$ cd /raid0pool/raid0share
[user@fedora-server raid0share]$ ls
[user@fedora-server raid0share]$ cd
[user@fedora-server ~]$ sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
[user@fedora-server ~]$ sudo systemctl restart smb
[user@fedora-server ~]$ sudo systemctl status smb
● smb.service - Samba SMB Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/smb.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-03-30 20:39:16 PDT; 7s ago
       Docs: man:smbd(8)
             man:samba(7)
             man:smb.conf(5)
   Main PID: 2953 (smbd)
     Status: "smbd: ready to serve connections..."
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 16590)
     Memory: 5.7M
        CPU: 68ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/smb.service
             ├─2953 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
             ├─2956 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
             └─2957 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group

Mar 30 20:39:16 fedora-server systemd[1]: Starting smb.service - Samba SMB Daemon...
Mar 30 20:39:16 fedora-server smbd[2953]: [2023/03/30 20:39:16.559559,  0] ../../source3/smbd/server.c:1741(main)
Mar 30 20:39:16 fedora-server smbd[2953]:   smbd version 4.17.6 started.
Mar 30 20:39:16 fedora-server smbd[2953]:   Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2022
Mar 30 20:39:16 fedora-server systemd[1]: Started smb.service - Samba SMB Daemon.
[user@fedora-server ~]$ sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
[user@fedora-server ~]$ 
[user@fedora-server ~]$ sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
[userr@fedora-server ~]$ sudo pdbedit -L | grep user
[sudo] password for user: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for user: 
user:1000:user
[user@fedora-server ~]$ cat /etc/passwd | grep user
user:x:1000:1000:user:/home/user:/bin/bash
[userr@fedora-server ~]$ ls -dZ /raid0pool/raid0share
unconfined_u:object_r:samba_share_t:s0 /raid0pool/raid0share
[user@fedora-server ~]$ ls -ld /raid0pool/raid0share
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Mar 30 18:35 /raid0pool/raid0share
[user@fedora-server ~]$ sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Smb.conf file

```
[global]
        workgroup = SAMBA
        security = user

        passdb backend = tdbsam

        printing = cups
        printcap name = cups
        load printers = yes
        cups options = raw

        # Install samba-usershares package for support
        include = /etc/samba/usershares.conf

[homes]
        comment = Home Directories
        valid users = %S, %D%w%S
        browseable = No
        read only = No
        inherit acls = Yes

[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/tmp
        printable = Yes
        create mask = 0600
        browseable = No

[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/drivers
        write list = @printadmin root
        force group = @printadmin
        create mask = 0664
        directory mask = 0775
[raid0share]
        comment = My Share
        path = /raid0pool/raid0share
        writeable = yes
        browseable = yes
        public = yes
        create mask = 0740
        directory mask = 0750
        write list = user
```

Comment: You called your share `share`. Access it as `\\192.168.5.207\share`

Comment: @GeraldSchneider

Thank you; I did fail to catch that. Unfortunately, I still run into issues. Attempting to connect to //192.168.5.207\share leads to an error stating 'Windows cannot access \\192.168.5.207\share. Check the spelling of the name. Otherwise, there might be a problem with your network'

Any suggestions?